# Can $n!$ be expressed as the sum of $n$ powers of 2?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

New here, so this question may be a little bit messy.

Also, I don't know if this has been asked yet, so sorry if this is a duplicate of another question.

Yesterday, I received the following question:

> (Dis)Prove, that for any positive integer $n$, $n!$ can be expressed as the sum of $n$ powers of $2$. (1 included)

For example, $9!=2^{18}+2^{16}+2^{15}+2^{11}+2^{8}+2^{6}+2^{5}+2^{4}+2^{4}$

I tried proving this question last night, but I just can't seem to prove it (I tried to used induction). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: argue that, is a number $N$ can be written as a sum of $n$ (possibly not distinct) powers of $2$, then the base $2$ expression for $N$ must contain no more than $n$ $1's$.

Comment: Note:  you'll get a better response if you show some effort.  How many $n's$ did you check?  Why do you imagine that this claim is true?  Can you find some $N>n$ which can't be written as the sum of $n$ powers of $2$?

Comment: @lulu, I checked n until n = 10. I imagine that this claim is true, since you can just use the greedy algorithm to check powers of 2. I haven't checked this in binary form yet, though. Up until today, I can't find some n which can't be written as the sum of n powers of 2.

Comment: Please edit your post to show how you write $10!$ as a sum of $10$ powers of $2$.

Comment: @lulu, by saying "I checked n until n = 10", I meant that I can calculate 9! as a sum of 9 powers of 2, but I can't calculate 10! as a sum of 10 powers of 2.

Comment: If one knows that $10!$ has at most $10$ bits equal to $1$, then one could repeatedly replace some terms $2^k$ with $2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}$ until the number of terms is finally equal to $10$.

Comment: OEIS: [A079584](http://oeis.org/A079584) (Number of ones in the binary expansion of $n!$)

Comment: @cineel The question is "Prove/disprove", but I unfortunately only added "prove" here. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by others,
the number of 1 bits
in $n!$ exceeds $n$ for
$n=10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20
$
and,
seemingly,
all larger $n$.

Here is a heuristic estimate,

$n!$ has about
$\dfrac{n(\ln(n)-1)}{\ln(2)}
$
bits.
Of these,
about the last $n$ bits
are $0$'s,
which leaves
$\dfrac{n(\ln(n)-1)}{\ln(2)}-n
=\dfrac{n(\ln(n)-1-\ln(2))}{\ln(2)}
$.

If these are equally
$0$ and $1$,
about half of these
should be $1$,
which is
$
\dfrac{n(\ln(n)-1-\ln(2))}{2\ln(2)}
$.
This exceeds $n$ by
$
\dfrac{n(\ln(n)-1-\ln(2))}{2\ln(2)}-n
=\dfrac{n\ln(n/(8e))}{2\ln(2)}
$
which is positive
for $n \ge 24$.

This agrees moderately well
with computations.
Dividing the actual
number of bits
minus $n$
by this gives this result
for $n$ from $20$
to $100$:

-1.65608, -7.56194, 32.5906, 8.60243, 2.92876, 1.98846, 2.68602, 2.60998, 2.74228, 1.82674, 2.58512, 1.38744, 1.12147, 1.30942, 1.55095, 1.74777, 1.1459, 1.48043, 1.3726, 1.52135, 1.30796, 1.33301, 1.1032, 1.32408, 1.34119, 1.05905, 1.24699, 1.30121, 1.49556, 1.32338, 1.29874, 1.2437, 1.10087, 1.20381, 0.931435, 1.19522, 1.23003, 1.03482, 1.04767, 1.17707, 1.20658, 0.92541, 1.08843, 1.17916, 1.12374, 0.857042, 1.0784, 0.992945, 1.10869, 0.904802, 1.135, 1.13861, 1.17401, 1.16042, 1.19321, 1.0003, 0.99127, 1.18187, 1.08536, 1.26508, 1.03766, 1.19737, 1.19731, 1.19712, 1.09911, 0.801583, 1.07863, 0.999876, 0.946624, 0.917429, 1.16037, 1.09619, 1.14919, 1.1694, 1.24926, 0.979809, 0.982215, 1.16607, 1.18389, 0.979308, 0.972214

This seems to be around $1$.

Note:
I used Mathematica's DigitCount
function for the computations.

Comment: Oops, ok. I guess I should recheck the question before asking it, haha.

Comment: That's ok. It was fun.

Comment: Hi Marty, OP here. Does the series 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20 (where the number of 1 bits in $n!$ exceeds $n$) continues a certain kind of pattern?

Comment: Don't think so. But I don't know enough to say anything more.

Answer (score 2):

The statement holds trivially for n=0,1.

Note that all even numbers can be written as $2^p(q)$ where q is odd.

Since n! is an even number for $n\ge2$,

Factor  $n!=2^p(q)$ where q is odd.

Since q is odd, $q= q^{'} + 1$ where $q^{'}$ is even.

$$ \implies n! = 2^p(q) = 2^p(q^{'} + 1) = 2^p + 2^pq^{'}$$

Now since $2^pq^{'}$ is even, the same factorisation can be repeated until the remnant is of the form $2^p.1$

Edit: Just realised that the question is asking to prove that it is the sum of n such powers of 2. Still leaving this answer in case this helps somebody figure out a different approach.

Comment: Reasonable answer. Thanks for answering.